# Nativescript Android Execution failed for task ':verifyReleaseResources'

Tags: android, nativescript

I am having below issue after upgrading nativescript version for android. Have been trying every possible suggestion on the internet for a week without any luck.

Here is the error :

> Execution failed for task ':verifyReleaseResources'.
>
> > java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource
> >     linking failed   Output:  error: resource style/Base.Theme.AppCompat
> >     (aka
> >     org.nativescript.nativescript_feedback:style/Base.Theme.AppCompat) not
> >     found.   error: failed linking references.

Here is my gradle.build file at platforms>android>build.gradle

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0',
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
}

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    } }

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: You don't really have to modify the gradle, have you updated your support libraries to latest? Have you installed platforms & build tools v28.x?

Comment: Yes I have installed sdk platform and build tools 28.0.3